# PyAthenaJDBC query string formatting issue

Tags: python, amazon-athena

I am trying to use the PyAthenaJDBC library to make a python script that will query an S3 bucket using Athena. The library is pretty great but I'm having issues with formatting.

I'm constructing the queries as strings in a separate function and passing the query string back to `cursor.execute(query)`.

The query string has quotes in it, and looks like this:

```
SELECT day, elb_name
    ,COUNT (*) AS c
    ,100.0 * (
        1.0 - (
            SUM (
                CASE
                    WHEN elb_response_code LIKE '5%' THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ) / cast(COUNT (*) as double)
        )
    ) AS success_rate
    ,100.0 * SUM (
        CASE
            WHEN backend_processing_time < 0.1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) / cast(COUNT (*) as double) AS t_lt_pt1
    ,100.0 * SUM (
        CASE
            WHEN backend_processing_time < 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) / cast(COUNT (*) as double) AS t_lt_1
    ,100.0 * SUM (
        CASE
            WHEN backend_processing_time < 5 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) / cast(COUNT (*) as double) AS t_lt_5
    ,100.0 * SUM (
        CASE
            WHEN backend_processing_time < 10 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) / cast(COUNT (*) as double) AS t_lt_10
    FROM elb_logs_raw_native_part
    WHERE year = '2017' AND
    month = '03' AND
    elb_name is not NULL AND
    elb_name != ''
    GROUP BY day, elb_name
    ORDER BY c DESC
```

This will cause a error on the second single quotation mark in the `LIKE '5%' statement.

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ''' (0x27) at index 186
```

I can avoid the error and successfully execute the query by changing this line in the library https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthenaJDBC/blob/master/pyathenajdbc/formatter.py#L115

from `return (operation % kwargs).strip()` to `return (operation).strip()` At this point in the code, `operation == query` (pasted above) and `kwargs == {}`

My specific question is, am I structuring my query incorrectly? Or is this something I don't understand about the native string formatting where trying to do a replace with an empty dictionary is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query is used as a string to be formatted, you need to double any `%` characters you want to survive as literal `%` characters.

Instead of `WHEN elb_response_code LIKE '5%' THEN 1`, use `WHEN elb_response_code LIKE '5%%' THEN 1`.  After the line you indicate in formatter.py runs, `%%` will have been transformed into a single `%`.

Comment: That was it. I should've seen that. Thanks!